# Add array to nested JSON if value from database is equal to string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have multiple tables in my database and  i want to join them together to create a nested JSON for a GET Request. At one point  i would like to add an array based on a value from the database e.g. (type === "fixValue").

```
 ... $sql = "SELECT name, type
            FROM section INNER JOIN question ON section.section_id = question.section_id
            WHERE  question.section_id = ".$row_section['section_id']."";

            $stmtq = $db->query($sqlq);
            $stmtq -> execute();

            while( $row_question = $stmtq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                $question_array['name'] = $row_question['name'];
                $question_array['type'] =  $row_question['type'];

                if($row_question['type'] == "fixValue"){

                    $question_array['options'] = array();

                }
                array_push($section_array['sectionQuestion'], $question_array);
            } ....
```

My json output now is:

```
{
"name": "Test",
"something": "Test",
"array1": [
    {
        "name": "Section",
        "array2": [
            {
                "name": "Something",
                "type": "fixValue",
                "options": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Sometthing2",
                "type": "notFixValue",
                "options": []
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

My desired output:

```
    {
"name": "Test",
"something": "Test",
"array1": [
    {
        "name": "Section",
        "array2": [
            {
                "name": "Something",
                "type": "fixValue",
                "options": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Sometthing2",
                "type": "notFixValue",
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

So the options array gets not only added to the item with the value "fixValue". Items with different type value as "fixValue" should be without "options" array.
Any ideas how to achive something like this?

Comment: can you please provide your current output and also the format in which you expect your final output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using counter instead of array_push:

```
... $sql = "SELECT name, type
            FROM section INNER JOIN question ON section.section_id = question.section_id
            WHERE  question.section_id = ".$row_section['section_id']."";

            $stmtq = $db->query($sqlq);
            $stmtq -> execute();
            $cnt = 0;
            while( $row_question = $stmtq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                $question_array['name'] = $row_question['name'];
                $question_array['type'] =  $row_question['type'];

                if($row_question['type'] == "fixValue"){

                    $question_array['options'] = array();

                }
                $section_array['sectionQuestion'][$cnt] = $question_array;
                unset($question_array);
                $cnt++;
            } ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When i do that it doesnt change. If the specific type comes at the second place though, it does leave the first entry empty. But then in the next Array it does add the array to every item again. Like:              
                    "type": "notFixValue"
                },
                {
  
                    "type": "fixValue",
                    "options": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
          [
                {
                    "type": "notFixValue",
                    "options": []